# How to approve Github pull request using access token?

Tags: python, github, github-api

As per API documentation https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-review-for-a-pull-request

We can use a CURL to approve pull request i.e.

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token ghp_TOKEN" \
 -X POST -d '{"event": "APPROVE"}' \
 "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/reviews"
```

but I get this error:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

Although, the CURL is working fine for other APIs like:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token ghp_TOKEN" \
 -X POST -d '{"body": "some message"}' \
 "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{pull_number}/reviews"
```

I have tried everything to make this work. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: FYI, this one is absolutely not working and giving the same error:


`curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls/42/reviews \
  -d '{"commit_id":"commit_id"}'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After bit of experiments, it has worked with API `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/reviews`

I must say that Github documentation is very poor that I have to spend almost 3 hours to figure this out. A small but proper CURL would have helped in a few seconds and would have saved my time.

Anyway, leaving this solution on StackOverflow so that, this helps other people and saves their precious time.

CURL:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token ghp_BWuQzbiDANEvrQP9vZbqa5LHBAxxIzwi2gM7" \
 -X POST -d '{"event":"APPROVE"}' \
 "https://api.github.com/repos/tech-security/chatbot/pulls/4/reviews"
```

Python Code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token ghp_BWuQzbiDANEvrQP9vZbqa5LHBAxxIzwi2gM7',
}

data = '{"event":"APPROVE"}'

response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/repos/tech-security/chatbot/pulls/4/reviews', headers=headers, data=data)

print (response.json())
```

Note: above github token is dummy, so don't freak out please! :D

Comment: For anyone wondering, in GitHub Enterprise Server, the URL structure to use in the CURL command is: `https://[enterprise-hostname]/api/v3/repos/${{github.repository}}/pulls/${{github.event.number}}/reviews`